# How do I send emails and keep my application responsive at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have this application with with a tabControl, and all the other necessary controls.

So the main task for the application is to send emails and if I send 1 that's fine, the application is unresponsive for 2 seconds max.
But if I try to send out like 10 however.. that makes my application unresponsive for 20 seconds. Now that's not a very good thing as you can imagine.

I've been trying threading but it keeps giving me an error about the UI operations have to be performed in the owning thread.

It's the last three lines that are giving me a hard time because I'm grabbing the names from the first Tab in the tabControl from the first ListView, then I use them when I press the button in the second tab and I try to pass them over to the third tab where they finally sets and goes into the second listView.

It works but it puts the application "On hold" while doing this process and I tried using Threading but I couldnt manage to get it working.

How do I properly thread this function or do I not thread?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LearningTol
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(ListViewItem email in lvEmails.Items)
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress(tbUsername.Text);
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Text));
                msg.Subject = "Subject";
                msg.Body = tbMessage.Text;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(msg);

                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(email.Text);
                lvi.SubItems.Add("Done!");
                lvFinishedEmails.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a more "Visual" reference.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach would be to make the button click handler `async` and `await` the IO bound work, the `SendAsync` method in this case (instead of the sync `Send` method). This also takes care of resuming on the correct thread for you. So your code would look like:

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListViewItem email in lvEmails.Items)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(tbUsername.Text);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.Text));
        msg.Subject = "Subject";
        msg.Body = tbMessage.Text;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        await client.SendMailAsync(msg);

        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(email.Text);
        lvi.SubItems.Add("Done!");
        lvFinishedEmails.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

As an aside, you usually wouldn't return have an `async void` method, you'd usual return a `Task` or `Task<T>` when using `async`, but event handlers are one of the few exception cases.

Comment: Isnt there a need for Await somewhere?

Comment: That's right, see the line that reads `await client.SendAsync(msg);`

Comment: Oooh yeah I do!

Comment: you need to pass alot of parameters though.

Comment: Ah, apologies! The method should be `SendMailAsync`

Comment: Works like a charm! +1